# Hide <pwa-install >Install </pwa-install> from PWA Builder if the app is installed

Tags: progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

I am using the new webcomponent `<pwa-install >Install </pwa-install>` to install my PWA app build using PWA Builder. The button works well but the only problem I have is that I cant make it to disappear if the app has already been installed.

I have tried to hide the install button and only show it when the `beforeinstallprompt` is activate but I failed with that:

```
self.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.deferredPrompt = e; 
  $("#installbanner").show();
});
```

I also tried the `appinstalled` method, that did not work as well.

```
self.addEventListener('appinstalled', (evt) => {
    app.logEvent("App is installed");
          $("#installbanner").show();
});
```

I also tried displaying all the available methods that are contained within the `<pwa-install >Install </pwa-install>` but it just showed jibrish.

I am really sorry to bug everyone, may you please kindly assist

Answer (score 2):

you can try using media display query, for example you can try one of the following properties:

```css
@media all and (display-mode: standalone) {
  pwa-install{
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```